# What is the meaning of "Magic Password"?

Tags: meaning, politeness

Russian «волшебное слово» (magic word) usually refers to «спасибо», «пожалуйста» и «будьте добры» (thank you, you are welcome, please).

Is it the same? If so, why «password»?

UPD.

> — Can you guys /some request/?
>   — Maybe with the magic password?

Comment: No, it is not. _password = watchword, key word, **magic word** (informal), open sesame_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard someone say "magic password" for this, so I can't really answer your question except to tell you that the **normal** phrase used for this is "magic word", just like in Russian.

> Kid: Mom, can I have another cookie?
>   Mom: What's the magic word?
>   Kid: Please?
>   Mom: Here you are. Last one you're getting today.

As far as my personal experience goes we pretty much only use "What's the magic word." when referring to "please". For "thank you" I generally hear

> Mom (continued from above): What do you say?
>   Kid: Thank you, Mommy!

If there's a standard prompt for "you're welcome", I'm not aware of one.

---

It's worth noting that most people only ever do this with children and using this with an adult is usually done as a joke/when teasing them or else can seem rather condescending.